# Compare values in methods

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to vue and I am trying to compare old value of input versus the new value in the input during focus and blur events.

I have the following code but now I want to compare if the value `inputBefore` and `inputAfter` are equal or not. How can I do that if I add if condition with the two values inside methods function I get an error.

Code can be found here: https://codepen.io/eladnn/pen/mdJWmbL

```
methods: {
    handleFocus(inputBefore) {
    console.log(inputBefore.target.value);
},
handleBlur(inputAfter) {
    console.log(inputAfter.target.value);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, maybe there is a hook on change of the value which contains old and new value. The most obvious solution to me is to have a separate variable inside of the component where you save the old value to and which you then compare on change of the value to the new one.

Comment: you can put your input in localstorage and compare it with new input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold the input on focus in a separate variable (here: inputOnFocus) and compare that to the value on blur:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!',
      input:'',
      inputOnFocus: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFocus(inputBefore) {
      this.inputOnFocus = (inputBefore.target.value) ? inputBefore.target.value : '';
    },
    handleBlur(inputAfter) {
      if(this.inputOnFocus === inputAfter.target.value) {
        console.log('Input did not change');
      } else {
        console.log('You changed the input from "' + this.inputOnFocus + '" to "' + inputAfter.target.value + '"');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="model" @focus="f_val = model;" @blur="b_val = model; get_val()">
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  f_val: "",
  b_val: "",
    model:""
  },
 methods: {
  get_val() {
   console.log(`value at focus ${this.f_val} | value at blur ${this.b_val}`)
  }
 }
})
</script>
```

you can try the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devatquarxps/suo8wdn5/7/)